# Error retrieving city name from google maps autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am having difficulties retrieving the city name in event 'place_changed' of autocomplete google maps.

The problem is that I am using javascript to load the map and and also the auto-suggestions.

I have to use the city selected from google maps component and use it in typescript file from javascript.

I am able to use the function from maps.js into typescript component but not able to retrieve the city name, as the event that changes do not trigger the whole function.

Maps.js

```
function initMap(coords) {
    var city = '';
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: coords,
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coords,
        map: map,
        zoom: 10,
    });

    var input = document.getElementById('city');

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
    // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
    // bounds option in the request.
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    // Set the data fields to return when the user selects a place.
    autocomplete.setFields(
        ['address_components', 'geometry', 'icon', 'name']);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
    infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
        infowindow.close();
        marker.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

        if (!place.geometry) {
            // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
            // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
            window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
            return;
        }

        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
        }
        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);

        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
                (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
        }

        infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

city.component.html

```
<div>
  <input id="city" type="text" class="form-control mr-5" placeholder="Enter a location" value="">
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <span id="place-name" class="title"></span>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
```

and i need the name of city on create-events.ts to save into database.So the structure is:

1. First the create-events.page.ts is loaded which contains a `<ion-item>` which when clicked loads the city.components.ts
2. Then the city.component.ts calls the function initMap() which is located in maps.js

And i need to retrieve the city name from maps.js into create-events.ts page if possible.

Comment: the html code shown is not event-create.html but city.component.html , sorry for misstyping.

Comment: You are using a lot of traditional javascript techniques on here which could be causing problems. Angular / Ionic do a lot to the html, so normal examples aren't always going to work. The sections are built using web components which encapsulate and change the structure around. To start with I would recommend looking into https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native-google-maps

Comment: I have looked into that but the autocomplete-google-maps search is not provided. Also i have tried to write the code in city.component.ts without creating the maps.js and import the js into ionic project but i ran into some undefined functions because of typescript.So i found the only solution to create maps.js and import in ionic project and load the maps, for autocomplete search.